# DNN 7 - SMTP stopped working

Tags: dotnetnuke

I configured the SMTP setting om my DNN 7 siteand everything worked fine for weeks. I tried to send  a newsletter today and discovered that there is a problem with the SMTP (even though i have changed nothing). I checked the configuration and verified that it hasn't been changed. And indeed it hasn't. I tried a few email accounts that i have and received the same error time and time again. Here is the error:

> There has been an error trying to send the test email. The error is:
>   There is a problem with the configuration of your SMTP Server. Mail was not sent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I checked the error and it appears that i used all my allowed emails out by the email server. I guess this is one of the first thing i should have checked...I suggest you to do that if it ever happens to you :)